# Call the file name to a textbox that is type file MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Edit View so to edit my records. One of the fields is a file. May I change the value of "Chose a file" with the name of the file?

I have try this but it doesn't work

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.file, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", type="file" name = "file", @Value = Model.file} })
```

I need that because the file name is going to null when I save the record from Edit View.

thank you

Comment: If you dont want the user to change the actual file content and only change the fiel name then You need to have a property called `FileName` in your model and then use `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileName)` , you need to prefill this file name in your controller side..

Comment: thank you for the comment, unfortunately I need to be editable so the user can change the file so to upload something else

Comment: @Reddy I thought to use your idea, but then I need a button or an action link so to open windows explorer and to update the textboxfor value. But I dont know how to write the correct javascript

Comment: Ok from what I can uderstand you want to show the file name inside the browse box instead of the `choose a file` text in your edit mode. This I doubt it cannot be done in straight forward manner, jquery will be required. But here is what you can do, just show the file name as a lable, and give this browse box to overwrite the file,

Comment: I suppose you mean label. If I do this then if the user doesn't choose a new file the record loose the current filename and it returns again to null.

Comment: you are right, This involves some javascript / Jquery.

Comment: You cannot set the value of an `<input type="file" />` - it would be a major security issue if you could

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, a file input cannot be set with a value. The user must choose a file from their filesystem to set the value.

You should use a view model with a propert of `HttpPostedFileBase` to hold the file upload, and in your post action conditionally only overwrite the value on your entity if that property has a value.

If you need the field to be required, then you must either remove the error on post if the entity already has an upload or manually require it only in your create action.

- Remove the error (assuming you're using `[Required]` on the property):

  ```
  if (entity.file != null)
  {
      ModelState["file"].Errors.Clear();
  }
  ```
- Conditionally require (don't use `[Required]` on the property and instead in your create action:

  ```
  if (model.file == null || model.file.ContentLength == 0)
  {
      ModelState.AddModelError("file", "You must upload a file");
  }
  ```